# How can I pass parameters from page1.html to server.php and return results to page2.php using ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a myfiles.php page that scans directory and displays a list of files with a radio button beside each file, and I have a load button that sends the name of the file selected to server.php which gets the data from the file and sends it back. 
My problem is I don't want the results to be sent back to myfiles.php, instead I want the result to be sent back and the browser to take me to editor.php.

Myfiles.html:

```
<table>
<form>
<?php 
$dir    = "./userFiles/".$login;
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')); 
foreach($files as $ind_file){ 
?> 
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="files" value="<?php echo $ind_file;?>"></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></td></tr>
<?php 
} 
?> 
</form>
</table>
<br/><button id="load">load</button>
<script>
$("#load").click( function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : server.php,
        type: 'post',
        data : {
            filename : $("input[name=files]:checked").val(),
            action : 'load'
        },
        success : function(html) {
           editor.setValue(html);
        }
    });
});
```

server.php:

```
$this->dir = "userFiles";
$this->filename = isset($_POST['filename']) ? $_POST['filename'] : false;
 private function load() {
        $content = @file_get_contents($this->dir.$this->filename);
        echo $content;
    }
```

Editor.php

```
<textarea id="code" name="code" autofocus></textarea>
<script>
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {
    mode: 'text/html',
    tabMode: 'indent',
    lineNumbers: true,
    lineWrapping: true,
    autoCloseTags: true
});
</script>
```

Please help modify the code to solve my problem. Thank you.

Comment: So basically you want to submit a form and redirect to another page where you can use the data from the form. Sounds eerily familiar, if I could just remember what does something like that, I think it has something to do with forms, action and HTML ?

Comment: @adeneo I wanna use ajax not a form

Comment: I see that, but using ajax to submit a form, then redirecting to another page, makes no sense ?

Answer (score 0):

First off you want to put all your [input] elements on a form.

```
<form name="load" action="<YOUR PHP SCRIPT>" method="post">

<?php 
$dir    = "./userFiles/".$login;
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.')); 
foreach($files as $ind_file){ 
?> 
<tr><td><input type="radio" name="files" value="<?php echo $ind_file;?>"></td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $dir."/".$ind_file;?>"><?php echo $ind_file;?></td></tr>
<?php 
} 
?> 
<input type="submit" value="Load">
</form>
```

Server.php and Editor.php can be combined.
Your PHP will look like this:

```
<?php
$selectedfile = $_POST['files'];
$content = file_get_contents("<YOUR DIRECTORY>" . $selectedfile);
?>
```

Now you can inject the $contents into your html

```
<HTML>

<div><?php echo $contents; ?></div>

</HTML>
```

Comment: I want to use ajax not form

Comment: You can use Ajax to call a php script, that script will then respond. You take that response[1], and input it into an HTML element. Using this method, the user would never leave the page.